# Error during MediaProxy installation

Tags: python, compiling, proxy, gcc, media

I am installing mediaproxy on my server debian. Please review the error pasted below. I have also tried installing the dependencies but still this error occurs. Need help on this.

```
root@server:/usr/local/src/mediaproxy-2.5.2# ./setup.py build   
running build  
running build_py   
running build_ext     
building 'mediaproxy.interfaces.system._conntrack' extension    
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -DMODULE_VERSION=2.5.2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c mediaproxy/interfaces/system/_conntrack.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/mediaproxy/interfaces/system/_conntrack.o
mediaproxy/interfaces/system/_conntrack.c:12:29: fatal error:   
      libiptc/libiptc.h: No such file or directory 

  #include <libiptc/libiptc.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Thanks.
Faisal

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases **so Debian is *unfortunately* off-topic here as well.** However, on [unix.se], a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is showing you that the file `/usr/include/libiptc/libiptc.h` could not be found. `/usr/include/libiptc/libiptc.h` is part of the `iptables-dev` package. To fix this problem, use:

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-dev
```

then retry `setup.py`